# KeyError despite definition of names at read_csv()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

I'm trying to print a column of a `pandas.dataframe`. However, this continuously fails, despite me explicitly assigning the column names using the `names` parameter in `pandas.read_csv()`.

Given the following code:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t',
                   names=['Symbol', 'Date', 'Type', 'Value'],
                   index_col=[0])
print(data)
```

Produces this:

```
             Date      Type         Value
Symbol                                       
benchmark  2011-12-01       dax  1.422847e+08
benchmark  2011-12-02       dax  1.958363e+08
benchmark  2011-12-05       dax  1.922807e+08
benchmark  2011-12-06       dax  1.477339e+08
benchmark  2011-12-07       dax  1.354372e+08
```

But this:
    print(data['Date'])

Produces this:

```
KeyError: 'Date'
```

From What I can tell I'm doing the exact same thing as described in `Python for Data Analysis` by McKinney on Page 123. Except I'm not getting any output besides that error.

The Data is in this format:

```
Symbol\t2015-01-01\tType\tFloat_Value
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what does `data.columns.tolist()` show?

Comment: `['2011-12-01', 'dax', '142284736']` - which is odd, because I thought passing `names` takes care of setting column names?

Comment: Correction: It shows `['Date', 'Type', 'Value']`; i had some other test code running before, where I didnt pass `names`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that you don't have spaces in your column-names

you may try to use `sep='\s+'` instead:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+',
                   names=['Symbol', 'Date', 'Type', 'Value'],
                   index_col=[0])
```